# Chemical shift difference methyl groups in 4-hydroxy-2,5-dimethyl-3-hexanone

Tags: stereochemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

Can someone explain why the NMR Spectrum of 4-hydroxy-2,5-dimethyl-3-hexanone shows a chemical shift difference for the methyl groups at the end? Why aren't the other carbons have a difference?
Below you see the NMR spectrum:[image]

Comment: There are four methyl groups and four relevant peaks. What is the problem?

Comment: C-2 is a chiral centre, so both C-5's are diastereotopic, likewise with both C-6's. https://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/nmr/05-hmr-08-symmetry.htm

Comment: Thanks, the website really helped to understand the issue.